# How to get server IP from given url

Tags: dns, ip, http, url

Can anyone tell me how to get the IP of a server, for example:

> https://capi-eval.signnow.com/api/document/

I need it for curl call, which might be slow because of dns.

I can't get ip with ping or  any other tool I can think of.

What am I missing here? Also how to do this?

Comment: If there is no prevention you can simply ping without protocol HTTP or HTTPS. For instance type `ping google.com` In CMD, The response will be **216.58.206.174**. For HTTPS protocol it will be 216.58.206.174:443 (by default) meaning on port 443 and for HTTP protocol it will be 216.58.206.174:80 meaning on port 80.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From command prompt:

`nslookup capi-eval.signnow.com`

`dig capi-eval.signnow.com`

Which returns:

```
Server:  resolver1.dyndnsinternetguide.com
Address:  216.146.35.35

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    ec2-54-147-193-212.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Address:  54.147.193.212
Aliases:  capi-eval.signnow.com
```

Ping reply often is shut off now to prevent useless DDOS attacks simply by flood pinging a server with requested maximum reply packet size among other things.

Note that if this is an AWS server you control, you can turn on ping reply through the security firewall. Otherwise you have to get the IP by other means. The assigned IP for this server is probably pretty static, so a single DNS query probably is sufficient to establsh the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried this ? CMD --> ping www.signnow.com

Comment: damn i could have sword iu tried it >.<

Comment: can check again, now with https://capi-eval.signnow.com/api/document/

Comment: @Jonzi - You don't ping a URL, you ping the server. `ping capi-eval.signnow.com` and pinging the server name still requires DNS to resolve the IP address.